# Coordinates conversion according the matrix shape

Tags: ruby, arrays, math, matrix, coordinates

I would like to convert an index in a flattened array into a coordinate in a multi-dimension array.

*Example:*
In the following 2-dimension array whose size is [3, 3]:

```
[
  [ -, -, - ],
  [ *, -, - ],
  [ -, -, - ]
]
```

the coordinate of `*` is [0, 1]. If we flatten this array as:

```
[ -, -, -, *, -, -, -, -, - ]
```

coordinate (or the index) of `*` becomes 3. How can we do the opposite? That is, a method  like:

```
index_to_coordinates([3, 3], 3)  # => [0, 1]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your `index_to_coordinates` takes `[3, 3]` (in addition to the flattened index `3`) as an argument, but that is redundant. The information you need is that each line in the matrix is of length `3`, and that the flattened index is `3`.

```
3.divmod(3).reverse # => [0, 1]
```

`divmod` gives you a pair the quotient and the remainder. Since you are expecting the order: x-coordinate (remainder) then y-coordinate (quotient), you need `reverse` to flip the order.

**Edited according to change in the question**

Note: I assume ruby 1.9 in the following. I do not want to bother with ruby 1.8. If necessary, please translate it to ruby 1.8 on your own. It should be easy.

Suppose you have a structure:

```
[
  [
    [0, 1, 2, 3]
    [4, 5, 6, 7]
    [8, 9, 10, 11]
  ]
  [
    [12, 13, 14, 15]
    [16, 17, 18, 19]
    [20, 21, 22, 23]
  ]
]
```

so that the size of this structure is represented as [2, 3, 4]. In general, we can express the size as an array `sizes`. You can convert this into an array `flattened` that represents the size of each dimension when the whole structure is flattened upto that dimension:

```
flattened = sizes.dup.drop(1)
(1...flattened.length).reverse_each{|i| flattened[i-1] *= flattened[i]}
```

With the particular example:

```
flattened # => [12, 4]
```

This means that the largest cycle is 12, the next is 4. Suppose you want the coordinate of `7`. In order to get that, you do:

```
index = 7
coordinate = flattened.each_with_object([]) do |size, array|
  quotient, index = index.divmod(size)
  array.push(quotient)
end
coordinate.push(index)
```

This will give you:

```
coordinate # => [0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Wow, impressive! Thank you Sawa.  However, if the matrix gets more then 2 dimensions, this method don't seem to work.

Comment: @Zag can you add examples of higher-dimension matrices (or tensors)?

Comment: An example of 3 dimensions matrix, NArray.object(2,3,2): 
[ [ [ nil, nil ], 
    [ nil, nil ], 
    [ nil, nil ] ], 
  [ [ nil, nil ], 
    [ nil, nil ], 
    [ nil, nil ] ] ]

Comment: Many thanks, Sawa. Your solution is just awesome. I'm currently trying to understand it :) I think I'll also trying to find a general mathematical rule for this. It's strange that NArray (which is a so powerful lib) don't provide a method for this, while it provide the opposite (if I have a 3x3 matrix named 'a', I can get the element number 3 using directy a[3], or of course a[0,1], as given in this cheat sheets: http://narray.rubyforge.org/SPEC.en).